# Find the equation of tangents for $x^3+y^3-3xy=0$ at $x=0,y=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

$$x^3+y^3-3xy=0$$

Find the equation of tangents at $x=0,y=0$

My attempt is as follows:-

**Attempt $1$:**

$$3x^2+3y^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}-3\left(x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y\right)=0$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}(y^2-x)=y-x^2$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}$$

but when placing $x=0,y=0$ we are getting undefined quantity.

But actual answer is $xy=0$, how can we proceed here?

**Attempt $2$:** (Parametric method)
$$\dfrac{y}{x}=t$$
$$y=xt$$

Putting this in the original equation

$$x^3+x^3t^3-3x^2t=0$$
$$x^2(x+xt-t)=0$$
$$x=\dfrac{t}{t+1}$$

$$y=\dfrac{t^2}{t+1}$$

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\dfrac{2t(t+1)-t^2}{(t+1)^2}}{\dfrac{t+1-t}{(t+1)^2}}$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=t^2+2t$$

$x=0$, then $\dfrac{t}{t+1}=0 \implies t=0$

$y=0$, then $\dfrac{t^2}{t+1}=0$ also $\implies t=0$

So we are getting slope as $0$, hence $y=0$ can be the answer, but actual answer is $xy=0$

Comment: I think you should make the equation in the parametrized form

Comment: Seconding Jo Jomax's suggestion. Set $y/x=t$ and you can solve both $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$. You will be at the origin when $t\to0$ and $t\to\pm\infty$. Anyway, this curve is the Folium of Descartes, and has been handled on our site (and in Wikipedia) many times over. Do search!

Comment: I have attempted the parametric metric and I have put it as Attempt $2$ in the post, but from there I am only getting $y=0$

Comment: Search for _tangent_ _cone_.

Answer (score 1):

Continue with what you obtained

$$y'= \frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x} $$

and note that the near the origin, $y' = \frac yx$, or

$$\frac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}  = \frac yx \implies x^3+y^3 = 2xy$$

Then, substitute $x^3+y^3 - 3xy=0$ to obtain the equation near the origin,

$$xy=0$$

which represents the $x$- and the $y$-axes and also the tangent lines of the given curve at the origin.

Comment: but the problem is that you are not calculating $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at $x=0$ at first

Comment: @user3290550 -  note that y’ = y/x is only valid near the origin, which makes y’ at x = 0 implicit

Comment: sorry I am not able to understand , see $y'=\dfrac{y-x^2}{y^2-x}$, now if we try to find $y'$ at $x=0,y=0$ then the quantity is undefined, so how to find $y'$  at $(0,0)$ because after finding $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at origin, then only we can put it in equation $y=mx$ right?

Comment: @user3290550 - instead of finding y' at origin explicitly, the answer finds the form of the curve near origin, which is xy = 0. It represents two axis lines x=0 and y=0, and their respective tangent lines are y=0 and x=0, which combine as xy = 0 as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, as you have noted, the tangent line is ill-defined at $(0,0)$. See the [plot at this link](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3%2By%5E3-3xy%3D0). There are two distinct tangent lines at $(0,0)$: $x=0$ and $y=0$ (hence the 'answer' of $xy=0$), depending on where you are 'in time', i.e. imagine tracing the curve out in time, at one time (let's say drawing left to right), $y=0$ would be the appropriate tangent while at another $x=0$ would be the appropriate tangent. If this curve were given parametrically, we would have an 'obvious' choice but as it stands there is no way of choosing one tangent over the other. This is the same issue one runs into in definition the addition law for elliptic curves in the case of the [nodal cubic](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~arapura/graph/nodal.html). As a final note, a parametrization is given [at this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes), where you can then as you have derive the appropriate tangents.